# Extending user reference

Tags: users

I have built a content type named "Project" which will showcase some projects by the members of a group. I have used a user reference field in that content type, so that the contributors of a project can be enlisted.

Now I am trying to put in the user's profile page the links to the projects he contributed to. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out my own ... I created a page view with url 'user/%/project' and added a contextual filter so that when no filter value is present, it gets filter value by getting user ID from url. Then added it to the navigation menu, and I was done.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use views and panels. You will create a new user home page using panels. Within that panel you will want to create a view that lists all the content types `Project` filtering on the user.

Otherwise, you will need to create your own module.